# How to perform zipping between two DStreams in Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

I have two windowed dstreams that I would like to zip like the normal zipping in RDDs.

Note : The main goal is to calculate the mean and stdv of the window dstream in case there is a better way to calculate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used DStream's transformWith to use this rdd operation and this solved my problem.

Example :

```
  valueStream.transformWith(mean, (rdd1: RDD[Int], rdd2 : RDD[Double]) => {rdd1.zip(rdd2)}
```

Comment: Could you add some details?

Comment: valueStream.transformWith(mean, (rdd1: RDD[Int], rdd2 : RDD[Double]) => {rdd1.zip(rdd2)}

Comment: I am just curious about what happens if the batch interval of each DStream is different? Could you elaborate upon that please?